# Saving checkbox states with isotope

Tags: javascript, local-storage, jquery-isotope

I am using [this example](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/btFfG) for multi checkboxes with isotope but I want to save the checkboxes state so when page is loaded, the filter is saved.

I tried to add my code to local storage here:

```
function getComboFilter( filters ) {
  var i = 0;
  var comboFilters = [];
  var message = [];

  for ( var prop in filters ) {
    message.push( filters[ prop ].join(' ') );
    var filterGroup = filters[ prop ];
    // skip to next filter group if it doesn't have any values
    if ( !filterGroup.length ) {
      continue;
    }
    if ( i === 0 ) {
      // copy to new array
      comboFilters = filterGroup.slice(0);
    } else {
      var filterSelectors = [];
      // copy to fresh array
      var groupCombo = comboFilters.slice(0); // [ A, B ]
      // merge filter Groups
      for (var k=0, len3 = filterGroup.length; k < len3; k++) {
        for (var j=0, len2 = groupCombo.length; j < len2; j++) {
          filterSelectors.push( groupCombo[j] + filterGroup[k] ); // [ 1, 2 ]
        }

      }
      // apply filter selectors to combo filters for next group
      comboFilters = filterSelectors;
    }
    i++;
  }

  var comboFilter = comboFilters.join(', ');

  // add local storage here
  localStorage.setItem("items", comboFilter);

  return comboFilter;
}
```

but I am having trouble loading the filters back from local storage and update it again when user makes changes. Where do I read local storage and make the changes?